# How does the helper method helps reduce duplication of code?

Tags: java, object, getter-setter, code-reuse, boilerplate

I'm doing an assignment, and I have a working piece of code without just the helper function given in the picture. The only part I don't understand is how the private helper method is supposed to reduce code duplication?
[image: Here's my assignment ScreenShot]

Comment: that´s a question your professor should be able to answer..

Comment: If the private method is called more than once, it avoid duplicating it's code.

Comment: @MauricePerry, But it takes a DateTime object as parameter? What exact piece of duplicated code do you think it reduces?  Thanks

Comment: @JesinYeldho it doesn't matter: if the method didn't exist, all the calls to it would need to be replaced by its code (hence duplication of code).